# Easiest way to clone live Ubuntu Server installation

Tags: server, 20.04, backup, raid

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 for testing purposes and yesterday was the backup day - hardly to say backup, just removing the second drive from the `md` RAID 1, attaching it to another machine and then making full clone on another drive, then returning it again to the testing machine. Easy, not a problem to wait for the rebuild (10GB used space), but for production machine this is a no-go. Any ideas how to backup the whole installation (not the drives/partitions, only the used space) on external drive while the server is still running?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only realistic way of getting *the whole device* would be to use a file system snapshot. You can do this with a ZFS partition or, if the server is a VM with its storage on a SAN, you can use the SAN management tools.

Comment: Is the goal to minimize down time? Lower downtime = Bigger budget. How tiny is the downtime you can afford? An hour? Ten minutes? Forty seconds? Less than one second? Your budget will govern, so what's the budget?

Comment: Not to minimize downtime, it's a small server for a small customer. All queries in the database are already logged, I just need a better way to clone/image the system while it's working